# How can I understand if my 2008 highlander sport has regular or sport tuned suspension?

Tags: toyota, repair, struts, highlander

I just bought a used 2008 highlander sport AWD. How can I make sure if it does have a regular or sport tuned suspension?

I want to change it's front struts and don't know what exact part should I buy?

Comment: If you are taking it to a mechanic as stated in your last question then that's something for them to figure out. If you plan to try and do this yourself it's going to mean a significant investment in tools, time and you'll need to be able to lift the car.

Comment: @GdD: I can not do that with the car's regular jack?

Comment: No @GoodMan, if you are going to do anything other than replace a tire you'll need a couple of jack stands.